# Efficient way to display a survey one statement at a time on single webpage

Tags: javascript, html, web

So I'm new to HTML/CSS and web development and I'm designing a site to host an online-based Likert-scale survey. I initially had the site set up so when the participant clicked on the link the entire survey would be displayed on the page with the submit button at the bottom of the page. However, my professor wants it designed in such a way that only one survey statement is displayed at a time, and the user can hit "Previous" or "Next" to navigate through the survey.

I've written some code which accomplishes this, but it seems incredibly inefficient to me. There has got to be a better way to do what I'm attempting to accomplish!!

Here's a sample of the approach I've been taking:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showNext(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
function showPrevious(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
</script>

    <div id="div1" class="center">
    <table align="center" style="font-size: 14px"  bgcolor="CCCCCC">
    <tr><td>A survey statement goes here<td></tr></table>
    <table align="center" style="font-size: 14px"  bgcolor="CCCCCC">
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="1">Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="2">Disagree (2)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="3">Neutral (3)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="4">Agree (4)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="5">Strongly Agree (5)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s1" value="0" checked><i>not answered</i></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type="button" disabled>Previous</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showNext('div2','div1')">Next</button>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="center" style="display:none">
    <table align="center" id="t1" style="font-size: 14px"  bgcolor="CCCCCC">
    <tr>Another statement goes here!</tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="1">Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="2">Disagree (2)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="3">Neutral (3)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="4">Agree (4)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="5">Strongly Agree (5)</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="s2" value="0" checked><i>not answered</i></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPrevious('div1','div2')">Previous</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="showNext('div2','div1')">Next</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, there HAS to be a better way to do this. If I keep going with this approach it will be a total pain to delete/add or reorganize survey statements later on.

Any links or tips would be greatly appreciated!

******SOLUTION******
I ended up coming up with a solution using looping/echo in php. Here's a rough (not pretty) sample of the code I used to accomplish my task:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go(){
document.getElementById('state0').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('state0').scrollIntoView();
}
function showNext(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";

    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
function showPrevious(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";

    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
</script>


<button type='button' onclick='go()'>GO</button>

<!--<button type='button' onclick="go()">go</button>-->
    <?php
    $numElements=5;
    $array = array("This is the first statement", "This is the second statement","This is the third statement","This is the fourth Statement", "Last statement here");

    for($i=0;$i<$numElements;$i++){

    $divId='state'.$i; 
    $sId='q'.$i;
    $nextInt=$i+1;
    $prevInt=$i-1;
    $nextDiv='state'.$nextInt;
    $curDiv='state'.$i;
    $prevDiv='state'.$prevInt;
    if($i==0){
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' disabled>Previous</button>
    <button type='button' onclick='showNext(\"$nextDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Next</button>
    </div>";}
    else if($i==$numElements-1){
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' onclick='showPrevious(\"$prevDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Previous</button>
    <button type='button'  disabled>Next</button>
    </div>";}
    else{
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' onclick='showPrevious(\"$prevDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Previous</button>
    <button type='button' onclick='showNext(\"$nextDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Next</button>
    </div>";    }

    }


    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all who provided help!!

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I can use any means necessary to make the survey, but I've never used jQuery before.

Comment: What part of the code do you want to make smaller?

Comment: Well, if you notice, I have a separate div for each statement in the survey. Furthermore, I have 2 buttons for each <div> which call javascript functions with parameters I've hardcoded. If I have a survey of 50 questions, my html file is going to be HUGE! Also, it would be a total pain to delete a statement from the survey if I continue with this approach.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Will the general form of the questions be all the same?  (question, and 1 through 5 agree/disagree choices)

Comment: Yup, all the statements will be answered with using a Likert-type scale (so the user selects a 1-5)

Comment: I'm curious, but is this the only thing that you are tasked to do or do you have other web dev duties?  Also, how are you planning/storing the data collected?  If this isn't your primary duty, maybe you should consider using a free service to build the survey quickly ie. surveymonkey, then embed the survey to your website via iframe?  Otherwise, what you are doing is basically what needs to be done to create surveys.

Comment: He mentioned his professor, so I'm assuming it's for a class of some sort.

Comment: Well, if you are building it for school/assignment, then instead of creating a Next/Prev button for each question, you can have 1 set of Next/Prev buttons for the entire survey and each click iterates through a collection of questions (ie table tags) and toggles a class.  If that's what you're looking for, I can create some code for you.

Comment: It is for school, but not homework or anything. I'm helping a professor with his research. I'm pretty sure he doesn't want to use SurveyMonkey or anything as he has his own servers. Will, would you mind creating me a sample of what you're proposing? Since my experience is limited, it's hard for me to visualize what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it may sound complicated, I would simplify it like that:

Create an array or json with all questions as key-value pair 
(like e.g. questions = [[1, "Do you like xy?"], [2, "2nd question],...],
having only one table for all questions and using a function that initially sets
the first entry of the array as 1st question. Call this function on clicking prev/next
to navigate through the questions and save the values in another array stored as 
data-attribute on the table.
Just as small demo a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/d5e0txve/) to demonstrate how this could work.

```
var questions = [[1, "how are you"],[2, "next one"],[3, "question number 3"]];

setFirstQuestion();

function setFirstQuestion(){
  $(".question").text(questions[0][1]);
  $(".question").data("current",[0][0]);
}

$("#next").click(function(){
   setNextQuestion();
});

function setNextQuestion()
{
  var current = $(".question").data("current");
  $(".question").text(questions[current + 1][1]);
  $(".question").data("current", current + 1);
}
```

This could just set the questions in your table, so instead of having 50 tables you would just use one. It's no full solution but only a suggestion how it could be done saving some of your time.

Answer (score 2):

Store your content as a datastructure.  Generate the survey on the fly.

```
function MakeQuestion(Q) {
    var lq = document.createElement('div');
    /* ... */
    return lq;
}

var Questions = [ { q: "Ham?", a: ['yes', 'double-yes', 'super-yes', 'bacon too'] }, ... ];

Questions.map(function(Q) {
    document.getElementById('qContainer').appendChild( MakeQuestion(Q) );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go(){
document.getElementById('state0').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('state0').scrollIntoView();
}
function showNext(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";

    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
function showPrevious(divIdShow,divIdHide){
    document.getElementById(divIdShow).style.display="block";

    document.getElementById(divIdHide).style.display="none";
    }
</script>


<button type='button' onclick='go()'>GO</button>

<!--<button type='button' onclick="go()">go</button>-->
    <?php
    $numElements=5;
    $array = array("This is the first statement", "This is the second statement","This is the third statement","This is the fourth Statement", "Last statement here");

    for($i=0;$i<$numElements;$i++){

    $divId='state'.$i; 
    $sId='q'.$i;
    $nextInt=$i+1;
    $prevInt=$i-1;
    $nextDiv='state'.$nextInt;
    $curDiv='state'.$i;
    $prevDiv='state'.$prevInt;
    if($i==0){
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' disabled>Previous</button>
    <button type='button' onclick='showNext(\"$nextDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Next</button>
    </div>";}
    else if($i==$numElements-1){
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' onclick='showPrevious(\"$prevDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Previous</button>
    <button type='button'  disabled>Next</button>
    </div>";}
    else{
    echo "<div id='$divId' class='center' style='display:none'>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
    <tr><td>$array[$i]<td></tr></table>
    <table align='center' style='font-size: 14px'  bgcolor='CCCCCC'>
        <tr><td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='1'>Strongly Disagree  (1)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='2'>Disagree  (2)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='3'>Neutral  (3)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='4'>Agree  (4)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='5'>Strongly Agree  (5)</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='$sId'  value='6'>No answer  </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button type='button' onclick='showPrevious(\"$prevDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Previous</button>
    <button type='button' onclick='showNext(\"$nextDiv\",\"$curDiv\")'>Next</button>
    </div>";    }

    }


    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Again,here's the answer